# Laravel installation and create-project issue

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

I was facing an issue to install laravel in my ubuntu. Please help me.

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel blog
```

I am getting this error. I had tried various options to solve this. And it never happened before.

```
Installing laravel/laravel (v8.0.1)
Installing laravel/laravel (v8.0.1): Loading from cache
Created project in blog
> @php -r "file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');"
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Package operations: 106 installs, 0 updates, 0 removals
Installing voku/portable-ascii (1.5.3): Loading from cache
Installing symfony/polyfill-php80 (v1.18.1): Loading from cache
Installing symfony/polyfill-mbstring (v1.18.1): Loading from cache
Installing symfony/polyfill-ctype (v1.18.1): Loading from cache
Installing phpoption/phpoption (1.7.5): Loading from cache
Installing graham-campbell/result-type (v1.0.1): Loading from cache
Installing vlucas/phpdotenv (v5.1.0): Loading from cache
Installing symfony/css-selector (v5.1.5): Loading from cache
Installing tijsverkoyen/css-to-inline-styles (2.2.3): Loading from cache
Installing symfony/var-dumper (v5.1.5): Loading from cache
Installing symfony/deprecation-contracts (v2.2.0): Loading from cache
Installing symfony/routing (v5.1.5): Loading from cache
Installing symfony/process (v5.1.5): Loading from cache
Installing symfony/polyfill-php72 (v1.18.1): Loading from cache
Installing paragonie/random_compat (v9.99.99): Loading from cache
Installing symfony/polyfill-php70 (v1.18.1): Loading from cache
Installing symfony/polyfill-intl-normalizer (v1.18.1): Loading from cache
Installing symfony/polyfill-intl-idn (v1.18.1): Loading from cache
Installing symfony/mime (v5.1.5): Loading from cache
Installing symfony/polyfill-intl-grapheme (v1.18.1): Loading from cache
Installing symfony/string (v5.1.5): Loading from cache
Installing phpdocumentor/reflection-common (2.2.0): Loading from cache
Installing webmozart/assert (1.9.1): Loading from cache
Installing phpdocumentor/type-resolver (1.3.0): Loading from cache
Installing phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock (5.2.1): Loading from cache
Installing psr/log (1.1.3): Loading from cache
Installing symfony/polyfill-php73 (v1.18.1): Loading from cache
Installing symfony/http-foundation (v5.1.5): Loading from cache
Installing psr/event-dispatcher (1.0.0): Loading from cache
Installing symfony/event-dispatcher-contracts (v2.2.0): Loading from cache
Installing symfony/event-dispatcher (v5.1.5): Loading from cache
Installing symfony/error-handler (v5.1.5): Loading from cache
Installing symfony/http-kernel (v5.1.5): Loading from cache
Installing symfony/finder (v5.1.5): Loading from cache
Installing psr/container (1.0.0): Loading from cache
Installing symfony/service-contracts (v2.2.0): Loading from cache
Installing symfony/console (v5.1.5): Loading from cache
Installing symfony/polyfill-iconv (v1.18.1): Loading from cache
Installing doctrine/lexer (1.2.1): Loading from cache
Installing egulias/email-validator (2.1.20): Loading from cache
Installing swiftmailer/swiftmailer (v6.2.3): Loading from cache
Installing brick/math (0.9.1): Loading from cache
Installing ramsey/collection (1.1.1): Loading from cache
Installing ramsey/uuid (4.1.1): Loading from cache
Installing psr/simple-cache (1.0.1): Loading from cache
Installing opis/closure (3.5.7): Loading from cache
Installing symfony/translation-contracts (v2.2.0): Loading from cache
Installing symfony/translation (v5.1.5): Loading from cache
Installing nesbot/carbon (2.39.2): Loading from cache
Installing monolog/monolog (2.1.1): Loading from cache
Installing league/mime-type-detection (1.4.0): Loading from cache
Installing league/flysystem (1.1.3): Loading from cache
Installing league/commonmark (1.5.4): Loading from cache
Installing dragonmantank/cron-expression (3.0.1): Loading from cache
Installing doctrine/inflector (2.0.3): Loading from cache
Installing laravel/framework (v8.1.0): Loading from cache
Installing fideloper/proxy (4.4.0): Loading from cache
Installing asm89/stack-cors (v2.0.1): Loading from cache
Installing fruitcake/laravel-cors (v2.0.2): Loading from cache
Installing psr/http-message (1.0.1): Loading from cache
Installing psr/http-client (1.0.1): Loading from cache
Installing ralouphie/getallheaders (3.0.3): Loading from cache
Installing guzzlehttp/psr7 (1.6.1): Loading from cache
Installing guzzlehttp/promises (v1.3.1): Loading from cache
Installing guzzlehttp/guzzle (7.0.1): Loading from cache
Failed to execute unzip -qq  
'/home/suraj/Documents/blog/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/1bba4d447795efc234ccc89b858ab8a1' -d 
'/home/suraj/Documents/blog/vendor/composer/44c036a4'

[/home/suraj/Documents/blog/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/1bba4d447795efc234ccc89b858ab8a1]
End-of-central-directory signature not found.  Either this file is not
a zipfile, or it constitutes one disk of a multi-part archive.  In the
latter case the central directory and zipfile comment will be found on
the last disk(s) of this archive.
unzip:  cannot find zipfile directory in one of 
/home/suraj/Documents/blog/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/1bba4d447795efc234ccc89b858ab8a1 or
    
/home/suraj/Documents/blog/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/1bba4d447795efc234ccc89b858ab8a1.zip, 
and cannot find 
/home/suraj/Documents/blog/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/1bba4d447795efc234ccc89b858ab8a1.ZIP, 
period.

The archive may contain identical file names with different capitalization (which fails on 
case insensitive filesystems)
Unzip with unzip command failed, falling back to ZipArchive class
Installing dnoegel/php-xdg-base-dir (v0.1.1): Loading from cache
Installing nikic/php-parser (v4.9.1): Loading from cache
Installing psy/psysh (v0.10.4): Loading from cache
Installing laravel/tinker (v2.4.2): Loading from cache
Installing scrivo/highlight.php (v9.18.1.2): Loading from cache
Installing filp/whoops (2.7.3): Loading from cache
Installing facade/ignition-contracts (1.0.1): Loading from cache
Installing facade/flare-client-php (1.3.5): Loading from cache
Installing facade/ignition (2.3.7): Loading from cache
Installing fzaninotto/faker (v1.9.1): Loading from cache
Installing hamcrest/hamcrest-php (v2.0.1): Loading from cache
Installing mockery/mockery (1.4.2): Loading from cache
Installing nunomaduro/collision (v5.0.2): Loading from cache
Installing sebastian/version (3.0.1): Loading from cache
Installing sebastian/type (2.2.1): Loading from cache
Installing sebastian/resource-operations (3.0.2): Loading from cache
Installing sebastian/recursion-context (4.0.2): Loading from cache
Installing sebastian/object-reflector (2.0.2): Loading from cache
Installing sebastian/object-enumerator (4.0.2): Loading from cache
Installing sebastian/global-state (5.0.0): Loading from cache
Installing sebastian/exporter (4.0.2): Loading from cache
Installing sebastian/environment (5.1.2): Loading from cache
Installing sebastian/diff (4.0.2): Loading from cache
Installing sebastian/comparator (4.0.3): Loading from cache
Installing sebastian/code-unit (1.0.5): Loading from cache
Installing sebastian/cli-parser (1.0.0): Loading from cache
Installing phpunit/php-timer (5.0.1): Loading from cache
Installing phpunit/php-text-template (2.0.2): Loading from cache
Installing phpunit/php-invoker (3.1.0): Loading from cache
Installing phpunit/php-file-iterator (3.0.4): Loading from cache
Installing sebastian/complexity (2.0.0): Loading from cache
Installing sebastian/lines-of-code (1.0.0): Loading from cache
Installing theseer/tokenizer (1.2.0): Loading from cache
Installing sebastian/code-unit-reverse-lookup (2.0.2): Loading from cache
Installing phpunit/php-code-coverage (9.1.8): Loading from cache
Installing doctrine/instantiator (1.3.1): Loading from cache
Installing phpspec/prophecy (1.11.1): Loading from cache
Installing phar-io/version (3.0.2): Loading from cache
Installing phar-io/manifest (2.0.1): Loading from cache
Installing myclabs/deep-copy (1.10.1): Loading from cache
Installing phpunit/phpunit (9.3.9): Loading from cache
symfony/routing suggests installing symfony/config (For using the all-in-one router or any 
loader)
Symfony/routing suggests installing symfony/yaml (For using the YAML loader)
symfony/routing suggests installing symfony/expression-language (For using expression 
matching)
symfony/routing suggests installing doctrine/annotations (For using the annotation loader)
paragonie/random_compat suggests installing ext-libsodium (Provides a modern crypto API that 
can be used to generate random bytes.)
symfony/event-dispatcher suggests installing symfony/dependency-injection
symfony/http-kernel suggests installing symfony/browser-kit
symfony/http-kernel suggests installing symfony/config
symfony/http-kernel suggests installing symfony/dependency-injection
symfony/service-contracts suggests installing symfony/service-implementation
symfony/console suggests installing symfony/lock
swiftmailer/swiftmailer suggests installing true/punycode (Needed to support 
internationalized email addresses, if ext-intl is not installed)
ramsey/uuid suggests installing ext-gmp (Enables faster math with arbitrary-precision 
integers using GMP.)
ramsey/uuid suggests installing ext-uuid (Enables the use of PeclUuidTimeGenerator and 
PeclUuidRandomGenerator.)
ramsey/uuid suggests installing ramsey/uuid-doctrine (Allows the use of Ramsey\Uuid\Uuid as 
Doctrine field type.)
ramsey/uuid suggests installing paragonie/random-lib (Provides RandomLib for use with the 
RandomLibAdapter)
symfony/translation suggests installing symfony/config
symfony/translation suggests installing symfony/yaml
monolog/monolog suggests installing graylog2/gelf-php (Allow sending log messages to a 
GrayLog2 server)
monolog/monolog suggests installing doctrine/couchdb (Allow sending log messages to a 
CouchDB server)
monolog/monolog suggests installing ruflin/elastica (Allow sending log messages to an 
Elastic Search server)
monolog/monolog suggests installing elasticsearch/elasticsearch (Allow sending log messages 
to an Elasticsearch server via official client)
monolog/monolog suggests installing php-amqplib/php-amqplib (Allow sending log messages to 
an AMQP server using php-amqplib)
monolog/monolog suggests installing ext-amqp (Allow sending log messages to an AMQP server 
(1.0+ required))
monolog/monolog suggests installing ext-mongodb (Allow sending log messages to a MongoDB 
server (via driver))
monolog/monolog suggests installing mongodb/mongodb (Allow sending log messages to a MongoDB 
server (via library))
monolog/monolog suggests installing aws/aws-sdk-php (Allow sending log messages to AWS 
services like DynamoDB)
monolog/monolog suggests installing rollbar/rollbar (Allow sending log messages to Rollbar)
monolog/monolog suggests installing php-console/php-console (Allow sending log messages to 
Google Chrome)
league/flysystem suggests installing league/flysystem-eventable-filesystem (Allows you to 
use EventableFilesystem)
league/flysystem suggests installing league/flysystem-rackspace (Allows you to use Rackspace 
Cloud Files)
league/flysystem suggests installing league/flysystem-azure (Allows you to use Windows Azure 
Blob storage)
league/flysystem suggests installing league/flysystem-webdav (Allows you to use WebDAV 
storage)
league/flysystem suggests installing league/flysystem-aws-s3-v2 (Allows you to use S3 
storage with AWS SDK v2)
league/flysystem suggests installing league/flysystem-aws-s3-v3 (Allows you to use S3 
storage with AWS SDK v3)
league/flysystem suggests installing spatie/flysystem-dropbox (Allows you to use Dropbox 
storage)
league/flysystem suggests installing srmklive/flysystem-dropbox-v2 (Allows you to use 
Dropbox storage for PHP 5 applications)
league/flysystem suggests installing league/flysystem-cached-adapter (Flysystem adapter 
decorator for metadata caching)
league/flysystem suggests installing league/flysystem-sftp (Allows you to use SFTP server 
storage via phpseclib)
league/flysystem suggests installing league/flysystem-ziparchive (Allows you to use 
ZipArchive adapter)
laravel/framework suggests installing ext-memcached (Required to use the memcache cache 
driver.)
laravel/framework suggests installing ext-redis (Required to use the Redis cache and queue 
drivers (^4.0|^5.0).)
laravel/framework suggests installing aws/aws-sdk-php (Required to use the SQS queue driver, 
DynamoDb failed job storage and SES mail driver (^3.0).)
laravel/framework suggests installing doctrine/dbal (Required to rename columns and drop 
SQLite columns (^2.6).)
laravel/framework suggests installing league/flysystem-aws-s3-v3 (Required to use the 
Flysystem S3 driver (^1.0).)
laravel/framework suggests installing league/flysystem-cached-adapter (Required to use the 
Flysystem cache (^1.0).)
laravel/framework suggests installing league/flysystem-sftp (Required to use the Flysystem 
SFTP driver (^1.0).)
laravel/framework suggests installing nyholm/psr7 (Required to use PSR-7 bridging features 
(^1.2).)
laravel/framework suggests installing pda/pheanstalk (Required to use the beanstalk queue 
driver (^4.0).)
laravel/framework suggests installing predis/predis (Required to use the predis connector 
(^1.1.2).)
laravel/framework suggests installing pusher/pusher-php-server (Required to use the Pusher 
broadcast driver (^4.0).)
laravel/framework suggests installing symfony/cache (Required to PSR-6 cache bridge (^5.1).)
laravel/framework suggests installing symfony/filesystem (Required to enable support for 
relative symbolic links (^5.1).)
laravel/framework suggests installing symfony/psr-http-message-bridge (Required to use PSR-7 
bridging features (^2.0).)
laravel/framework suggests installing wildbit/swiftmailer-postmark (Required to use Postmark 
mail driver (^3.0).)
guzzlehttp/psr7 suggests installing zendframework/zend-httphandlerrunner (Emit PSR-7 
responses)
psy/psysh suggests installing ext-readline (Enables support for arrow-key history 
navigation, and showing and manipulating command history.)
psy/psysh suggests installing ext-pdo-sqlite (The doc command requires SQLite to work.)
psy/psysh suggests installing hoa/console (A pure PHP readline implementation. You'll want 
this if your PHP install doesn't already support readline or libedit.)
filp/whoops suggests installing whoops/soap (Formats errors as SOAP responses)
facade/ignition suggests installing laravel/telescope (^3.1)
sebastian/global-state suggests installing ext-uopz (*)
phpunit/php-code-coverage suggests installing ext-pcov (*) 
phpunit/php-code-coverage suggests installing ext-xdebug (*)
phpunit/phpunit suggests installing ext-xdebug (*)
Writing lock file
Generating optimized autoload files
```

> Illuminate\Foundation\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump
> Script Illuminate\Foundation\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump handling the post-autoload-
> dump event terminated with an exception

```
[ErrorException]                                                             
require(/home/suraj/Documents/blog/vendor/composer/../guzzlehttp/guzzle/src  
/functions_include.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory    
                                                                           
create-project [-s|--stability STABILITY] [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--repository 
REPOSITORY] [--repository-url REPOSITORY-URL] [--dev] [--no-dev] [--no-custom-installers] [--no-scripts] [--no-progress] [--no-secure-http] [--keep-vcs] [--remove-vcs] [--no-install] [-- 
ignore-platform-reqs] [--] [<package>] [<directory>] [<version>]
```

Comment: make sure your internet is working

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem? According to that message, I would assume that there is a corrupted file in your cache

Comment: @NicoHaase, Yes man. Problem is Cache

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used this and It works for me.

```
composer clear-cache
```